# How to convert nested for loop to stream in Java

Tags: java, loops, java-stream

I'm trying to refactoring below code using Java 8 Stream.

How can I filter Issues which have Labels contain "Season1".

```
public List<GHIssue> getFirstSeasonIssues() throws IOException {
    List<GHIssue> firstSeasonIssues = new ArrayList<>();
    List<GHIssue> issues = repository.getIssues(GHIssueState.ALL);

    for (GHIssue issue : issues) {
        Collection<GHLabel> labels = issue.getLabels();
        for (GHLabel label : labels) {
            if (label.getName().equals("Season1")) {
                firstSeasonIssues.add(issue);
            }
        }
    }
    return firstSeasonIssues;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter` with `anyMatch` to locate all the issues having a matching label.

```
List<GHIssue> firstSeasonIssues =
    issues.stream()
           .filter(i -> i.getLabels().stream().anyMatch(l -> l.getName().equals("Season1")))
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note that this will add each issue that has a matching label once to the output `List`.

Your original loops may add the same issue multiple times to the output `List` if the "Season1" label appears multiple times for the same issue, but I believe you don't want to add the same issue multiple times.